# Hovering over presence indicator doesnt bring pop up

Tags: user-profile, configuration, presence-indication

I have some strange behavior. When im on user profile and i hover over the "prescense indicator" i do not get a pop up, as strange as it my seen ...
How could it be? Do i need to activate maybe something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I know it requires a special plugin to Internet Explorer - it can be not installed or corrupted. And I suppose it doesn't work in other browsers at all.

Comment: yes in firefox it didnt work when i tested, but what plug in should i have?

Answer (score 1):

The presense "popup" is an ActiveX control installed by OCS, Lync or Messenger. AFAIK it wonly works in IE 32bit (because the ActiveX are 32bit).  In SP there is some Javascript that calls the control and pops it up.

Are your status indicators for people showing as grey (which would indicate that the communication with Lync isnt operational) or green/orange/red which would indicate the communication is working with Lync.

Comment: it shows gray .. but it doesnt matter i just need to show a pop up when i hover over it and i have few environments with same portal, on some it works and on others it doesnt

Comment: If its grey then either your IM client isn't working/signed-in and connecting with the ActiveX control etc... OR the users address wasn't found in the IM client and so no presence is shown.